Enable rich text editor for event confirmation mail?
I've noticed that on the demo site - https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org, currently version 5.76.alpha - that the event confirmation mail text field is rich text.
On my installs it is a regular text field.
Was this rich text field introduced in a recent version of civi? Or is there a setting to enable/disable the rich text field for the email confirmation text?

Yes, its on recent version. You should be able to have in latest security release i.e 5.74.4
Also check if the 'Wysiwig Editor' is set to editor in Display preference(CiviCRM >> Administer >> Customize data and screens >> Display Preference)

Thanks Pradeep. I upgraded a site to 5.74.4 but it's still a regular text field. Do I have to enable the rich text fields somewhere?

Which fields you talking about?

Do you want to add the link of the form or a screenshot?

It works now. I had an error 500 that I had to resolve first.
Thanks!
